# Typeerror: a is undefined - ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

This is the first time im working with ExtJS. I'll show you what i have. I have a Model as:

```
Ext.define('osFamilyModel', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            fields: [
                    {name: 'osFamily'}
               ]
        });
```

and a store related to that model as

```
Ext.define('osFamilyStore', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
            model: 'osFamilyModel',
            proxy: {
                type: "ajax",
                url: "<lp:resourceURL id='fetchOsFamily'/>",
                timeout: 120000
            }
        });
```

lp mentioned here is the taglib that i used. And a combobox as

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
            id : 'editVmOsFamily',
            width : fieldWidth,
            renderTo : 'vmOsFamilyFieldContainer',
            store : 'osFamilyStore',
            queryMode : 'local',
            valueField : 'osFamily',
            displayField : 'osFamily',
            baseCls : 'third_span'
        });
```

I keep getting the error as **Typeerror: a is undefined** and cant seem to find it where. Can you guys help me find? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks guys, i solved this myself! not needed anymore.

Comment: @DarinKolev: i was missing comma in my code in another model thats why it was giving it i guss, once i placed it, worked like a charm